# Ruby array hash keys

Tags: ruby

Basically I'm working with a 2D matrix. I can access elements of the matrix by specifying an (x,y) pair to get the corresponding value at that position.

Now I also want to be able to keep track of certain pairs that are arbitrarily determined at run-time. For example, maybe I need to keep track of the values at (1,2), (3,4), and (5,6), and maybe I need to retrieve the value at that position frequently.

So I was thinking how about just make a hash .

```
liked_elements = {[1,2] => M[1,2], [3,4] =>M[3,4], [5,6]=>M[5,6]}
```

Or something like that.

Then I can quickly iterate over the hash and get the elements that I like.

Are there any issues with using arrays as hash keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's truly a matrix (an array of arrays), then you can just pass in coordinates like this

```
matrix = [[:a, :b, :c],[:d, :e, :f], [:g, :h, :i]]
matrix[0][1] # returns :b
matrix[1][2] # returns :f
matrix[2][3] # returns nil, since 3 is out of bounds
```

Yes, you can create an array as a hash key.

```
h = Hash[[0,1], matrix[0][1]]
h[[0,1]] # returns :b
```

Answer (score 5):

Just don't modify the array afterward (or remember to rehash the hash if you do).