# How does Ruby allow an array to be a Hash key?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I recently learned that you [can use an array as a Hash key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623602/ruby-array-hash-keys)

How does Ruby accomplish this?

- Is the Array pointer the hash key?
- Or is it the array_instance's object_id?
- Or something else?

Comment: the same way that any other object is used as a hash key... what's so special about arrays?

Comment: @rogerdpack clone on the array? That definitely doesn't happen.

Comment: @Doorknob educate me, please

Comment: Your question does not sound interesting as is, but if you modify the question a little bit and focus on why mutable objects (where different instances may potentially have the same value) can be a hash key, then the question becomes interesting, and the provided answers will still fit.

Comment: I'm receptive to that. Would you get the call rolling by proposing some edits? I'll clean up the rest. My thanks

Answer (score 5):

It isn't the pointer or the `object_id`. Ruby allows you to *sort of* treat arrays as values, so two arrays containing the same elements produce the same `hash` value.

Here, look:

```
arr1 = [1, 2]
arr2 = [1, 2]

# You'll see false here
puts arr1.object_id == arr2.object_id

# You'll see true here
puts arr1.hash == arr2.hash

hash = {}
hash[arr1] = 'foo'
hash[arr2] = 'bar'

# This will output {[1, 2] => 'bar'},
# so there's only one entry in the hash
puts hash
```

The `Hash` class in Ruby uses the `hash` method of an object to determine its uniqueness as a key. So that's why `arr1` and `arr2` are interchangeable in the code above (as keys).

Comment: The last paragraph is the key here. **Any** Ruby object can be used as a hash key thanks to Object's `eql?` and `hash` methods. The fact that Array overrides these to behave the way we expect is what makes it work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Two objects refer to the same hash key when their hash value is identical and the two objects are `eql?` to each other.

Okay, what does `Array#eql?` do?

> Returns true if self and other are the same object, or are both arrays with the same content (according to Object#eql?)

Comment: You’re looking for `Array#eql?`.